# Adding properties file to a maven build process

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to pass a properties file to maven command :

```
# prop files, java format
key1=VAL1
key2=VAL2
```

instead of adding cli arguments like:

> $ mvn clean verify -Dkey1=VAL1 -Dkey2=VAL2

i know its possible to do it sith setting.xml but i want to use simple java properties format file and not xml.

Comment: What are those system properties for? How are you going to use them?

Comment: @Tunaki This is used by jenkins for running tests. example - IP address of the server to run tests, the protocol, the port. etc.

Comment: You should check thing like [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) which has goals to get ports for local testing ?

Answer (score 1):

We have used the [properties-maven-plugin read-project-properties](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) goal for this. It's very nice for properties that apply to all POMs and for which you don't want hundreds of projects to have to simultaneously update to a newer corporate POM version. Change the property in the central location and updates are published instantly.

Typically we bind the goal to the `initialize` phase. The properties are available to any plugins goals that run after that phase.